# Can still do POST and GET, although nothing running on server

Tags: bash, google-chrome, unix, postman, netstat

On my server machine, I have an application that responds to port `9876`.

I've closed the application with `kill`.

If I do `netstat | grep 9876`, no process is shown.

However, I can still do `POST` and `GET` request to the server machine (from both Postman and Chrome) on port `9876`.

How is that possible?

Comment: Probably that application has spawned a sub process which is still alive.

Comment: So how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `netstat` doesn't show you listening sockets/process

Issue `sudo netstat -lp | grep 9876`, as Payalord mentioned, if you don't `sudo` you'll only list sockets controlled by your user. The last column will be `PID/Program name` which will help you find out who's keeping this socket open.

**man** pages are your friends:

```
   -p, --program
       Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.

   -l, --listening
       Show only listening sockets.  (These are omitted by default.)
```

As for avoiding the application from spawning a subprocess, you'll need to investigate this as there's not enough information here to know why it happens and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running commands on the right user, usually the best to run the commands on root user.

Also maybe better to run netstat like this: `netstat -tulpn | grep :9876`

Hope this helps to clarify the problem.